# Multiple Case Statements to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, case-statement

In my SQL Server database one customer could have many products.

When casing using this:

```
CASE
    WHEN br.Ptype# = 'LE' THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS [Legal],
CASE
    WHEN br.Ptype# = 'BR' THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS [BR],
CASE
    WHEN br.Ptype# = 'WS' THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS [Screen],
CASE
    WHEN br.Ptype# = 'TW' THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS [Van]
```

It returns:

```
Title   FirstName   LastName  Email                 Legal  BR  Screen  Van
Mr      Aaaa        Aaaa      test.email@test.com   N      Y   N       N
Mr      Aaaa        Aaaa      test.email@test.com   Y      N   N       N
```

How can I get the returned results to be a single row with the Legal as Y and the BR as Y as this customer has these 2 policy types? As I know this customer has 2 insurance types from my specified 4 I'm searching for I'd like it to return the results like:

```
Title  FirstName  LastName  Email               Legal  BR  Screen  Van
Mr     Aaaa       Aaaa      test.email@test.com Y      Y   N       N
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT --TOP 1000
dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF(yy.Name#,'H') AS [Title],
dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF(yy.Name#,'F') AS [FirstName],  
dbo.PARSE_NAME_UDF(yy.Name#,'L') AS [LastName],
yy.Email# AS [Email],
--br.PolRef@ AS [PolicyReference],
--bc.Datecreated# AS [Date Sold],
--br.Idat# AS [PolicyStartDate],
CASE
WHEN br.Ptype# = 'LE' THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END AS [Legal],
CASE
WHEN br.Ptype# = 'BR' THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END AS [BR],
CASE
WHEN br.Ptype# = 'WS' THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END AS [Screen],
CASE
WHEN br.Ptype# = 'TW' THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END AS [Van]

FROM brpolicy AS br
LEFT JOIN yyclient AS yy ON br.Ref@ = yy.Ref@ AND br.B@ = yy.B@
LEFT JOIN brcledger AS bc ON br.PolRef@ = bc.PolRef@ AND br.B@ = bc.B@

WHERE
br.Ref@ = 'AAAA06'
AND (br.Ptype# = 'WS'
OR br.Ptype# = 'LE'
OR br.Ptype# = 'BR'
OR br.Ptype# = 'TW'
)
```

Please ignore my br.Ref@ from the where clause as that's my test customer record

Comment: You might want to filter for Legal='Y' OR BR='Y'. A distinct select where you do NOT include these columns could be what you want...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAX`:

```
SELECT  Title,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        MAX(CASE
                WHEN br.Ptype# = 'LE' THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N'
            END) AS [Legal],
        MAX(CASE
                WHEN br.Ptype# = 'BR' THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N'
            END) AS [BR],
        CASE
            WHEN br.Ptype# = 'WS' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS [Screen],
        MAX(CASE
                WHEN br.Ptype# = 'TW' THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N'
            END) AS [Van]
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Title,
         FirstName,
         LastName
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
Select * from (SELECT  Title,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        CASE
            WHEN br.Ptype# = 'LE' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS [Legal],
        CASE
            WHEN br.Ptype# = 'BR' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS [BR],
        CASE
            WHEN br.Ptype# = 'WS' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS [Screen],
        CASE
            WHEN br.Ptype# = 'TW' THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
        END AS [Van]
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Title,
         FirstName,
         LastName) as tProduct where Legal = 'Y' and BR = 'Y'
```